# How to use CKReference cloudkit IOS Swift to create good structure for database?

Tags: cloudkit

i am creating cloudkit based app where i have to create database structure. I got stuck in CKReference. How i can use CKReference for creating a good database structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Design the CloudKit schema to store the portions of your app’s object model that you want to persist. If you are implementing an app from scratch, use the Model-View-Controller design pattern to separate the user interface views from the model objects. Then design a schema that efficiently stores the portions of the object model you want to store in iCloud."

Try these links (the second one likely answers your question directly):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckreference

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html

Comment: can i get all records once or there is limit for getting records ?

Comment: I am not sure. I typically use firebase or aws for my databases.

Comment: I have one question regarding firebase is that which database is best firestore and Real Time database ?

Comment: it depends on your goal. I have used both, although in my new apps I like firestore. Firestore is a document based database, so you get some really awesome features that the rtd does not have.

Comment: What i have experienced that firestore provides multiple queries but in case of RTD we cannot use multiple queries. You have used Firestore for Chatting ?

Comment: Yes, I have had no problems using firestore for a lot of different things. I have written  cloud functions for apis, messaging, and even coordinates. If I answered your qwuestion, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? I need 50 rep so I can comment :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer, can you please let me know about cloud functions for apis?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions, I wrote a backend to generate tokens for a rest API for Twilllio. The google docs are really good, but no matter what you will need to write some node.js. You can write functions on the server with cloud functions. Follow their instructions and it will be straight forward :)